# SQL Server : Datetime conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select CONVERT(date,d) as dateX 
from dates
where d >= '2008-01-01' and d< '2079-12-31'
```

`CAST(d as DATE)` caused the same error.

Where d is smalldatetime type in a one column dates dimension.

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Smalldatetime` is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx) to have a range between 1900-01-01 and '2079-06-06'.

Hence, your value is out of range.

Use `datetime` or `datetime2` or a maximum value in range -- say '2078-12-31'.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks

Comment: a bit late but better than never, to learn how to query my own questions.  Thanks